# python sometimes runs normally, but sometimes doesn´t do anything at all

Tags: python, pgzero

I am setting up python for the first time
I have a beginners book that I am following

This works fine from IDLE

```
for count in range(10):
    if ((count % 2) == 0):
        print(count)
        print ("is even")
    else:
        print(count)
        print("is odd")
```

and if I save it as

```
import pgzrun
for count in range(10):
    if ((count % 2) == 0):
        print(count)
        print ("is even")
    else:
        print(count)
        print("is odd")
pgzrun.go()
```

then it works fine by double-clicking the file

however this

```
def draw():
    screen.draw.text("hello", topleft=(10, 10))
```

appears to run, generates no error messages, but doesn't actually do anything at all, likewise this when you double-click it.

```
import pgzrun
def draw():
    screen.draw.text("hello", topleft=(10, 10))
pgzrun.go
```

Comment: You're missing the `()` after `pgzrun.go` in the last code block.

Comment: Well, your code only defines a function... What do you expect it to output?

Comment: You never call `draw()` in the second script.

Comment: The third and fourth samples put the code inside functions which are never called.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function with the `def` keyword in python will do just that: define the function and not call it. If you add parentheses to the function call `pgzrun.go` and double click it, your program will execute just as you have written it. If you want to see that text, you should call the draw function like `draw()`

Comment: Thanks to all, I got 4 answers all saying the same thing. I am fluent VBA but completely new to python (3rd hour so far!). Now I get it: def in python = sub in VBA, it doesn't do anything until called. I am trying to teach my 7 year old granddaughter it, and just followed what it said in the book slavishly. (Python Games for Kids by Carol Vorderman). That is the second time I have put in exactly what is says in the book and it hasn't worked. many thanks for all 4 answers.